# Quicksort in Go

Tags: go, quicksort

I'm learning Go, and tried to implement a quicksort, however it doesn't return a complete list. To my understanding of Go it matches with a functioning Ruby implementation I wrote.

My code is:

```
func quickSort(data []string) []string {
  if len(data) > 1 {
    pivot := data[0]
    smaller := make([]string, 0, len(data))
    equal := make([]string, 0, len(data))
    larger := make([]string, 0, len(data))
    for i := 1; i < len(data); i++ {
      if data[i] > pivot {
        larger = append(larger, data[i])
      } else if data[i] < pivot {
        smaller = append(smaller, data[i])
      } else {
        equal = append(equal, data[i])
      }
    }
    return append(append(quickSort(smaller), equal...), quickSort(larger)...)
  } else {
    return data
  }
}
```

I am very puzzled as to what in this doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted, it's a legit question.

Comment: compared to [tex.se], where I used to be very active, there is a tendency here to quickly downvote questions :(

Comment: I miss SO before the mods turned it into a fascist government, reminds me of `/r/technology`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bug you have is that you never append the pivot value to the returned slice. So for each recursive call, you will lose the pivot.

Make the following change to the code and it will work:

```
equal := make([]string, 1, len(data))
equal[0] = pivot
```

Comment: Sigh. I knew it was something painfully obvious.

Comment: Very nice pickup. I'm still trying to follow algorithmic-stuff in Go. This has helped :)